# Bootstrap accordion + DataTables

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I'm using [bootstrap 3 accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) and [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) for my tables but I can't seems to initialize DataTables inside a Bootstrap accordion

Assuming that the table below is inside a bootstrap accordion

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" class="materialTable">
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th>#</th>
     <th>Test</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>#</td>
     <td>Test</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is how I tried to initialize the table

```
$( function () {
    $('.materialTable').dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sClass": "text-center", "aTargets": [ 0,8 ] },
                         { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 8 ] }],
    });
});
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover materialTable">
```

class attribute declared two time its overriding on second attribute

Comment: I used class because the table is more than one. If I use ID it will be more complicated to handle the tables later.

Comment: you can use class but in html only once you add this attribute. you have added twice in one tag.